# Firing void when instantiating a class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, constructor

I would like to be able to fire some code whenever a class is instantiated.

In VB.NET WinForms I've done something like this:

```
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub
```

This works great, I'm now trying to do something similar in C# MVC.  Something like:

```
public class ViewModelBase
{
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
    public UserRegistrationInformation UserSession;

    public void GetUserInfo()
    {
        WebUsersEntities db = new WebUsersEntities();
        UserSession = db.UserRegistrationInformations.Where(r => r.uri_UserID == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public void New(){
        GetUserInfo();
    }

}
```

So whenever `ViewModelBase` is created it will automatically populate the `UserSession` string.

I've been trying to google this, but I can't seem to find anything which is annoying as it should be quite simple!

Comment: Just to make you code (and therefore the question) more clear: Please think about the naming of the method "New()" it do not tell anybody what it does. Further is something is calles "New" I would expect some return value (same for GetUserInfo). When you say "it will automatically populate the UserSession" I would expect a method like "PopulateUserSession()" somewhere in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I put New as it was the closest to the VB that I could come up with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# [constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ace5hbzh.aspx) are created as follows:

```
public class ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewModelBase() 
    {
        GetUserInfo();
    }
}
```

Notice how it is the same name as the `class`. The method `GetUserInfo` will be invoked each time a new instance of `YourClass` is created.

Answer (score 2):

A constructor is different in C#:

A constructor in VB is marked with the keyword `new`, in c# you do it by creating a method with the same name as the class. In c# `new` has no meaning as a special method (it's the equivalent of the `shadows`-keyword in VB, completely unrelated). The sample below show how to create a constructor in c#

```
public class ViewModelBase{

    public void ViewModelBase()
    {
        GetUserInfo();
    }

    public void GetUserInfo()
    {
        WebUsersEntities db = new WebUsersEntities();
        UserSession = db.UserRegistrationInformations.Where(r => r.uri_UserID == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId).FirstOrDefault();
    }   

}
```